# Cannot get the label of my taxonomy term

Tags: 8, theming

I'm quite new to twig but I've found out a couple things.

It seems like my code is reading the Taxonomy instead of the term inside. Because all of the icons in my code change when I have the following settings:

```
{% if topic_type %}
{% embed "node--teaser__field.html.twig" %}       
  {%- block field_icon -%} 
    {% if topic_type == 1 %}
        group 
    {% else %}
        tablet
    {% endif %}
  {%- endblock -%}  
  {%- block field_value -%} {{ topic_type }} {%- endblock -%}
{% endembed %}
{% endif %}
```

I have a taxonomy term called "Personeel" and I want the if statement to change the icon to "group" whenever the topic_type is "Personeel".

Comment: use the https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_vardumper and dump the `topic_type` like `{{dump(topic_type) }}` to see the value of it, and than use the if in twig like `{% if topic_type == "Personeel" %}`

Comment: The if statement responds to what is written (with a 1) and the 2nd to last line {{ topic_type }} responds with the line I want (Personeel). I cannot install vardumper because of dependency issues and I cannot use composer because I use a webserver.

Comment: What template is this? Some override of taxonomy-term.html.twig, or a field template for a term reference field?

Comment: I'm using Open Social, my theme is the social blue theme. But I know alot of it is based from the social base theme.